# Extracting a method from a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-function

I have the following static method, which returns all possible combinations of triples from an `IEnumerable<int>`, that are pythagorean. eg: for `int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, it will return `new[]{{3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 5}}`.

```
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetPythagoreanNumbers(IEnumerable<int> array)
    {
        return array.SelectMany((a, i) =>
        {
            var inner = array.Skip(i + 1);
            return inner.SelectMany((b, j) =>
                inner.Skip(j + 1)
                    .SelectMany(c => GetTriplePermutations(a, b, c)));
        });
    }
```

Now, `GetTriplePermutations()` returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, which represents a collection of arrays built from the 3 integers(a, b, c) received. Basically, the query returns all possible arrangements of 3 elements from the array, starting from left to right.
(eg: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} => new[]{ {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5} }`).
From all the triples returned by the query, `GetTriplePermutations()` chooses only the ones that satisfy my condition.

I've managed to make it work correctly, however, as I was refactoring, I spotted out that my query kinda
repeats itself, meaning that it has the same pattern of consecutive ext methods applied:

```
array.SelectMany((a, i)).Skip(x + 1).SelectMany((b, j)).Skip(y + 1)
```

So, in order to eliminate repetitions, I was trying to somehow extract a method, that would allow the code to be converted into something like this:

```
return OddMethod(array).SelectMany(c => GetTriplePermutations(a, b, c)));
```

Now, I have no idea how to do that, as part of my code is returned by a Linq query. I was thinking that this
"OddMethod"'s signature should look like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> OddMethod(int[] array)
```

, but can't progress any further. Any ideas how I could achieve this "method extraction" ? Thank you! :)

Comment: You might find this article by Eric Lippert useful https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help, I managed to find what I had been looking for:

```
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetPythagoreanNumbers(IEnumerable<int> array)
        {
            ThrowNullException(array);

            return array.SelectSkip((a, inner) =>
                inner.SelectSkip((b, result) =>
                    result.SelectMany(c => GetTriplePermutations(a, b, c))));
        }

 private static IEnumerable<T> SelectSkip<T>(
            this IEnumerable<int> source,
            Func<int, IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<T>> func)
        {
            return source.SelectMany((a, i) =>
            {
                var inner = source.Skip(i + 1);
                return func(a, inner);
            });
        }
```

I think I'll stay with the older version, though! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could always define a extension method what covers you logic and makes your code more readable.

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method

Pseudo-Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetTriplePermutations(tis IEnumerable<int> array)
{
    return array.SelectMany((a, i)).Skip(x + 1).SelectMany((b, j)).Skip(y + 1)
}
```

You can calling this function by using `OddMethod(array).GetTriplePermutations();`

Comment: Thanks! However, this would not solve my problem, as the code still repeats itself, but this time within the extension method